# Nginx Proxy pass with aws s3 gives 403

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-s3

I have an web app that uploads images in server and copies them to s3 bucket using awscli. Nginx on server retrieves images from s3 through reverse proxy. 
When I try to open image using url, it gives 403 response. But opening image from s3 bucket url doesn't seem problem at all.

Here is nginx proxy config:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache/s3 levels=1:2 keys_zone=s3cache:60m max_size=4G;
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name img.domain.com;

    location / {
            limit_except GET { deny all; }

            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;

            proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_set_header cookie "";

            proxy_hide_header x-amz-delete-marker;
            proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
            proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
            proxy_hide_header x-amz-version-id;

            proxy_hide_header etag;

            proxy_cache s3cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 28d;
            proxy_cache_valid 403 24h;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 24h;

            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            error_page 403 404 /404.html;

            proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/;

            add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            expires max;
    }
```

}

Bucket policies are correct.
Interesting, I found restarting nginx after every batch upload or waiting hours after upload, 403 response goes away.

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Post your nginx access / error log for an applicable request

Comment: @Tim I have access lof turned off and error log is blank.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to trouble shoot each step carefully. Nothing much I can suggest with the information available.